# Why does the android:src behaves weirdly on padding in drawable?

Tags: java, android

I recently did some test on android drawable and I found that the android:src behaviors to padding is extremely weird compare the android:background.

Here is my drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
                <padding
                    android:top="1dp"
                    android:right="1dp"
                    android:bottom="1dp"
                    android:left="1dp"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:top = 2>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/white"/>

            </shape>
        </item>
</layer-list>
```

Inside of the mainActivity layout I have another image view which I used to test. I set the image view to 40dp width and height. Then I tested the android:src vs the android:background attribute by setting them to my drawable above. Here is the result:

Android:src

[image]

Android:background

[image]

The android:background as you can see is the expected behavior because I move the white circle down 2 and it has padding that obeys the pink oval padding. Now the android:src is straight up unexpected because 1st of all the white oval which is the layer that is above the pink oval is not shown. Second of all, the shapes change to a flatten oval.

Any clue to why this is the case??????

Comment: Can you please share your ImagaView code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` works with `android:scaleType` where you can give different options [ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

whereas background always takes scaleType of `FitXY` covering full region for that view.

if you want the same behaviour as background with src,

put android:scaleType="FitXY". there are other options you should check also.